# Using SuperWebSocket to create a WebSocket Server

Tags: c#, webserver, websocket

I was looking for a way to implement a WebSocket server and came across SuperWebSocket which seems to have the most features. I downloaded the source code, looked at the samples (and the Echo server tutorial), but still have no clue how to do it.

I found [this guide](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/discussions/353151) and it seemed to point me in the right direction, but I get errors with the references. I add the references to all the dlls, and I manage to import them '`using Superwebsocket.Common`', but when I try to build I get an error telling me that they cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you describe sound similar to my problems trying to get the SuperWebSocketWeb demo up and running. I had a similar problems with the project references, which at design time in visual studio seemed fine but failed during a build.

To solve this I made sure that the demo project and SuperSocket assemblies were all built targeting the same .net framework version (4.5 in my case).